# Como "resetar" Python no Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python

Estou com problema em uma biblioteca Python em meu computador, nao consigo desinstalar ela através do pip. Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de remover a biblioteca "a força" ou restaurar o Python para configuração padrão.

Abaixo segue o erro ao tentar desinstalar através do pip:

> rafamttz@rafamttz:~/python2713/bin$ pip uninstall crossbar
>   Uninstalling crossbar-17.12.1:
>     /home/rafamttz/python2713/COPYRIGHT
>     /home/rafamttz/python2713/LICENSE
>     /home/rafamttz/python2713/LICENSE-FOR-API
>     /home/rafamttz/python2713/bin/crossbar
>     /home/rafamttz/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar-17.12.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst
>     /home/rafamttz/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar-17.12.1.dist-info/INSTALLER
>     /home/rafamttz/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar-17.12.1.dist-info/METADATA
>     /home/rafamttz/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/crossbar-17.12.1.dist-info/RECORD

...

> Proceed (y/n)? y
>
> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/rafamttz/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)
>     File "/home/rafamttz/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 76, in run
>       requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
>     File "/home/rafamttz/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 346, in uninstall
>       req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
>     File "/home/rafamttz/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
>       paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
>     File "/home/rafamttz/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
>       renames(path, new_path)
>     File "/home/rafamttz/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 267, in renames
>       shutil.move(old, new)
>     File "/home/rafamttz/python2713/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
>       os.unlink(src)
>
> OSError: [Errno 13] Permissão negada: '/home/rafamttz/python2713/COPYRIGHT'
>   You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Estou usando Python 2.7.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta instalação está no seu diretório pessoal mas, pelo visto você executou alguma ação com **sudo** aí e é a razão do **pip** não conseguir apagar os teus arquivos. Vá em '/home/rafamttz/python2713/' e verifique as permissões dos arquivos lá.

Comment: Giovanni, acabei reinstalando o SO, fiz o backup das coisas, o problema ja foi resolvido

Comment: Dica, use o virtualenv para criar ambientes isolados pro Python, daí o que você instala fica lá em um local específico e ainda é possível testar diversas versões do Python e dos módulos facilmente.